# How to define theme translation file?

Tags: translation

If I have WordPress installation in English, then I can define my theme translation file in the wp-config.php file with following:

```
define('WPLANG', 'sv_SE');
```

But if I have WordPress installed in the local language then there is already WordPress translation file defined there, then how can I define my theme translation file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends a bit if your current theme already supports localization.

Does your theme's function file contain something like this?

`load_theme_textdomain( 'twentytwelve', get_template_directory() . '/languages' );`

If not, add it in there. And change `twentytwelve` to your `theme-directory-name`.

After that create a directory called `languages` in the root of your theme a drop your localization file (`theme-directory-name-sv_SE.mo`) in there.

Comment: Theme is translatable and I have no problem using the translation file with the WordPress which is installed in the English language. But if I have WordPress installed in local language, then it where I can define in the wp-config file because theres already WPLANG defined as I said above.

Comment: You don't have to. If your theme supports localization, you have the theme's .mo file in the theme's `languages` folder, and your `wp-config.php` file contains `define('WPLANG', 'sv_SE');` you're done. (or you can start translating)

Answer (score 0):

If you add the following line to your `functions.php` file:

```
load_theme_textdomain( 'my_textdomain', get_template_directory( ) . '/languages' );
```

The language files for your themes will be loaded from that directory (in this case the `languages` directory in your themes' folder.
In this folder you can put your `sv_SE.po` file (or another extension if you wish to use other translation software).

More information about translating a WordPress theme can be found in [this article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/theme-development/translating-your-theme/) from Wptuts+.
More information about [`load_theme_textdomain()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/load_theme_textdomain) from the Codex pages.

Comment: Actually, *.po is just [Poedit](http://www.poedit.net/)'s extension name. It's the *.mo file you'll need.